# Strict Class Initialization in Typescript 2.7

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

So I created a sample project using the Visual Studio 2017 template 'ASP.NET Core Web Application' with Angular.
I updated the package.json created by default to the latest modules' versions.
After running the `npm install` command and launching the site I get and error related to TypeScript.

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/app/components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component.ts:9:12 
>       TS2564: Property 'forecasts' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
>
> Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>   client.js:67 [HMR] connected
>   client.js:160 [HMR] bundle has 1 errors
>   client.js:161 [at-loader] 
>   ./ClientApp/app/components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component.ts:9:12 
>       TS2564: Property 'forecasts' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

The error is quite clear. I researched a little bit and found out a new feature for the TS 2.7:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html

**Strict Class Initialization**

> TypeScript 2.7 introduces a new flag called --strictPropertyInitialization. This flag performs checks to ensure that each instance property of a class gets initialized in the constructor body, or by a property initializer. For example ...

This is the code where the error appears

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'fetchdata',
    templateUrl: './fetchdata.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
    public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
            this.forecasts = result.json() as WeatherForecast[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}

interface WeatherForecast {
    dateFormatted: string;
    temperatureC: number;
    temperatureF: number;
    summary: string;
}
```

And this is my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    //"skipLibCheck": true, // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17863. Remove this if you upgrade to a fixed version of Angular.
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strict": false,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "webpack-env" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

Then the VS intellisense doesn't complain but the error is still there when running.

I have also tried to define the `forecasts` field with `public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];` but it didn't help

**Node** v9.9.0
**TypeScript** 2.7.2
**Angular** 5.2.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define the field as being optional, as there will be a time interval between the constructor call and until you get the result of `get` that the field will be `null`. This does mean you will have to check that the field is not null where you use the field, but this is probably a good idea:

```
export class FetchDataComponent {
    public forecasts?: WeatherForecast[];
    // equivalent to: 
    // public forecasts: WeatherForecast[] | undefined;
    doStuff(){
        this.forecasts.push() // error Object is possibly 'undefined'
        if(this.forecasts != null) {
            this.forecasts.push(); // ok 
        }
        this.forecasts!.push() // We tell the compiler we know better and not to complain about Object is possibly 'undefined'
    }
}
```

Another option is to use the definite assignment assertion (`!`) which will tell the compiler the field will be initialized and will definitely not be `null` (a lie in this case). This exposes you to some runtime errors, but you will not need to check the fields on usage. I don't recommend this in this case, but it is your call:

```
export class FetchDataComponent {
    public forecasts!: WeatherForecast[];
    doStuff(){
        this.forecasts.push() // ok
        if(this.forecasts != null) {
            this.forecasts.push(); // ok too
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or he could try: public forecasts: WeatherForecast[] | undefined;

Comment: @rrd true, but that is just a more verbose way of writing `public forecasts?: WeatherForecast[]`. If you hover over `forecast` with the this declaration you will see the type is actually  `WeatherForecast[] | undefined`

Comment: @rrd added your version for completeness, 10x :)

Comment: I'll +1 this answer, covers all possibilities.